# MS Access: Group by months for each month between Start Date and End Date

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-date-functions

I have these four data fields - ID, SubscriptionStartDate, SubscriptionEndDate and MonthlyCost in MS Access. Subscription Start and End Date will cover multiple months or even years, I want to sum MonthlyCost for each individual month between Start and End Date for all the IDs.

Using SQL in Access, I am looking for an output like:

Month  TotalMonthlyCost

Jan-13    100000 -> total monthly cost for Jan-13, summed across all the IDs.

Feb-13    150000 -> total monthly cost for Feb-13, summed across all the IDs.
...

Comment: are you looking for all months to be reported by one query or one query per month?

Comment: @gordatron I need all the months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you could do something like this:

```
select
    m.month
    ,sum(d.MonthlyCost)
from
    months as m
    inner join data as d
        on d.SubscriptionStartDate < m.endDate
        and d.SubscriptionEndDate > m.start
group by
    m.month
```

You would need to **create the table "months"**  that would look like this:

```
   month   |    start   |   end
 'jan-13'  | 01/01/2013 | 31/01/2013
 'feb-13'  | 01/02/2013 | 28/02/2013
 'mar-13'  | 01/03/2013 | 31/03/2013
```

but this is saying if you are in that month at all (even for one day) then you rmonthly subscription should be added. Is that correct?

Note: i don't have access here and i cant remember if my syntax is perfect for access. (i think you need brackets in the join clauses or something)

Comment: Yes, even if the end date is 2nd Feb, we charge for full month [Evil Grin]. Sorry there is no data field called "Month", do we have to create it? Data only has four fields - ID, startDt, endDt and Cost.

Comment: You would have to create a whole other table with all months in it.. or at least all months you are interested in billing for. the start of your billing process could calculate in code what months are missing from the months table.. or you could just add all the rows to outlive your application now.

Comment: I guess its a kind of number table?.. or similar anyway http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable  it saves you have to iterate over rows or cycle through months. basically its like having a row for each iteration you want to perform allowing you to handle it as a set operation